# Grunt wiredep but choosing a different main file to import into index

Tags: gruntjs, bower, grunt-wiredep

I have installed **highcharts** through bower and I have the job `wiredep` running in grunt when I build. Highchart's `bower.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "highcharts",
  "version": "v5.0.7",
  "main": "highcharts.js"
}
```

So what happens is I get this in my index file:

`<script src="bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>`

but what I am after is `highstock.js` which is a part of the already installed highcharts library, however I can't add that in manually and keep running the `wiredep` because it will get replaced, and I also don't want to add it in outside of the `<!-- bower:js -->...<!-- endbower -->` as that'll define highcharts twice.

Is there a way I can do that **properly**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do that is to override the highcharts library in bower.json like so:

```
"dependencies": {
    "highcharts": "^5.0.7",
    "highcharts-custom-events": "^2.0.9"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "highcharts": {
      "main": "highstock.js"
    }
  }
```

That way I'm overriding the particular library and defining the main js. If you wanted multiple files you can define an array: 
`["dist/package-without-main.css", "dist/package-without-main.js"]`

Check `bower-overrides` for more details: https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#bower-overrides